# Microsoft SQL Server : comparing a vertical table as a horizontal table for vector

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of vectors where each vector has an element of a through z.

I would like to have a query such that that I get the first vector on the left and the comparing to vector on the right.

Let's say the first vector is (a,b,c) and the other two vectors are (a,b) and (c).

When I really want this:

```
v1  el1 v2  el2
-----------------
1   a   2   a
1   b   2   b
1   c   2   null 
1   a   3   null
1   b   3   null
1   c   3   c
```

This way it would be easy to have another pass to calculate the metrics per vector as they relate to vector #1.

```
DROP TABLE #vector

CREATE TABLE #vector (v VARCHAR(10),el VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #vector(v, el) VALUES ('1', 'a')
INSERT INTO #vector(v, el) VALUES ('1', 'b')
INSERT INTO #vector(v, el) VALUES ('1', 'c')
INSERT INTO #vector(v, el) VALUES ('2', 'a')
INSERT INTO #vector(v, el) VALUES ('2', 'b')
INSERT INTO #vector(v, el) VALUES ('3', 'c')

SELECT * 
FROM #vector a 
LEFT JOIN #vector b on a.el = b.el AND a.v <> b.v 
WHERE a.v = '1'
```

I actually get this:

```
v   el  v   el
--------------
1   a   2   a
1   b   2   b
1   c   3   c
```

I thought about PIVOT:

```
WITH vectors AS (
select *
from 
(  select v,el  from #vector ) src
PIVOT (
       count(el)  for el in ([a],[b],[c])
) piv) 
SELECT * FROM vectors a JOIN vectors b ON b.v <> a.v WHERE a.v=1
```

Which returns this:

```
v   a   b   c   v   a   b   c
------------------------------
1   1   1   1   2   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   3   0   0   1
```

Which admittedly, I can use but it requires me to rewrite simple summation query into one in which I must specify a through z.

```
SELECT 
    v, el, present 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM 
         (SELECT v, el FROM #vector) src 
     PIVOT (count(el) for el in ([a],[b],[c]) ) piv) foo
UNPIVOT (present FOR el IN (a,b,c)) AS up;
```

This returns:

```
v   el  present
------------------
1   a   1
1   b   1
1   c   1
2   a   1
2   b   1
2   c   0
3   a   0
3   b   0
3   c   1
```

So as a possible final answer:

```
SELECT v, el, present 
INTO #vector2
FROM (select * FROM (  select v,el  from #vector ) src PIVOT (      count(el)  for el in ([a],[b],[c]) ) piv) foo
UNPIVOT (present FOR el IN (a,b,c)) AS up;
SELECT * FROM #vector2 a LEFT JOIN #vector2 b on a.el = b.el  AND a.v <> b.v   WHERE a.v='1'
ORDER BY a.v,b.v
```

Returns:

```
v   el  present v   el  present
1   a   1   2   a   1
1   b   1   2   b   1
1   c   1   2   c   0
1   c   1   3   c   1
1   b   1   3   b   0
1   a   1   3   a   0
```

So through the PIVOT and UNPIVOT, I can get the zeros filled in.

However, this seems like a complicated solution.

Is there an easier way?

One idea would be to alter #vector and add 'present' and populate the zero entries. But populating the other zero entries wastes space and it is non-trivial to determine which 0s to insert.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You might also give http://codereview.stackexchange.com a shot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pivot/unpivot use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 2 as part, a.v as a_v, a.el as a_el, b.v as b_v, b.el as b_el
FROM #vector a 
LEFT JOIN #vector b on b.v='2' and a.el=b.el 
WHERE a.v='1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as part, a.*, b.*
FROM #vector a 
LEFT JOIN #vector b on b.v='3' and a.el=b.el 
WHERE a.v='1') t
order by part, a_v, a_el
```